# why I am not getting results from my uncompressing?

Tags: unix, operating-system, tar, tcsh, bsd

I am using a Dragonfly BSD system and I need to uncompress a folder for configuration purpose. I could not find results, the compressed file was still there without the uncompressed folder I should find. To test if the problem was something more specific I tried the same tar -xf but later also adding *v (verbose)* option with an ordinary text file but what I found was the **tar** showing me the uncompressed file when on the verbose, meanwhile I couldn't find it (by ls command) neither open it.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post photos of screen shots of text — copy'n'paste the text.

Comment: You specified `tar -xvf ntest.tar /jeff/` but none of the file names starts with `/` — you should specify `tar -xvf ntest.tar jeff/` to get the files extracted.  Incidentally, 'useful' only has one ell.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2):

You specified `tar -xvf ntest.tar /jeff/` but none of the file names starts with `/` — you should specify `tar -xvf ntest.tar jeff/` to get the files extracted.

<sup>*Incidentally, 'useful' only has one ell.*</sup>